# does charts (achartengine ) carry dynamically changing capability

Tags: android, codenameone

Does charts (AChartEngine) have these capability

1.Ability to add or remove legend

2. Ability to adjust the axis - both x and y (min and max) - ideally by using a finger pinch.
3. Ability to show a value if you hover over the point
4. Ability to show, hide a curve on demand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.Ability to add or remove legend

Yes.  Use the setShowLegend() method on the renderer.

> Ability to adjust the axis - both x and y (min and max) - ideally by
>   using a finger pinch.

For interactivity, you should move to the new Codename One charts package (which is based on the aChartEngine library).  It provides more features in this area.  You can enable pinch zoom and panning by specifying a flag.  Pinch zoom currently just works by zooming in (like on a photograph), so it doesn't necessarily adjust the axis.  If you can point me to an example of a chart that provides the type of behaviour you're looking for, I can take a look and recommend how it can be achieved.

> Ability to show a value if you hover over the point

The ChartComponent (in the new charts package) allows you to override the seriesPressed() and seriesReleased() methods to respond to clicks on points in the chart.  You can then display whatever you want in response.  These methods are passed events telling you which series (and data point) was pressed.

> Ability to show, hide a curve on demand

You can just modify the chart model (e.g. to remove/add a series), then repaint the ChartComponent.

Comment: I have attached new library but i got this exception `java.lang.NullPointerException at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.draw(XYChart.java:374) at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onDraw(GraphicalView.java:195) at org.achartengine.compat.View$Peer.run(View.java:208) at com.codename1.ui.Display$1.run(Display.java:775) at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176) [Task Thread] 0:0:0,0 - java.lang.NullPointerException [Task Thread] 0:0:0,1 - java.lang.NullPointerException ` Does it require rework on existing charts ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to rework existing charts.  Should work.   Are you modifying the chart off the EDT?

Comment: Not all, some part of that, avg temperature chart and scatter chart

Comment: What demo code?  Please post your code so I can see it.  Can't really comment further without seeing what you're doing.

Comment: I opened a new thread for this. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28529393/4423025)