# Chart does not render with the new CN1aChartEngine library

Tags: codenameone

Here is the code:

```
public Component getCombinedTemperatureChart(Context context) {

    /**
     *  Title for each line 
     */
    String[] titles = new String[]{"Temp 1", "Temp 2"};

    /**
     *  x-axis values
     */
    List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        x.add(new double[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12});
    }
    /**
     *  Value sets
     */
    List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    values.add(new double[]{12.3, 12.5, 13.8, 16.8, 20.4, 24.4, 26.4, 26.1, 23.6, 20.3, 17.2,
        13.9});
    values.add(new double[]{9, 10, 11, 15, 19, 23, 26, 25, 22, 18, 13, 10});
    /**
     *  Colors and Styles for renderer
     */
    int[] colors = new int[]{Color.GREEN, Color.rgb(200, 150, 0)};
    PointStyle[] styles = new PointStyle[]{PointStyle.CIRCLE, PointStyle.DIAMOND};

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildRenderer(colors, styles);
    renderer.setPointSize(5.5f);
    int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        XYSeriesRenderer r = (XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
        r.setLineWidth(5);
        r.setFillPoints(true);
    }
    setChartSettings(renderer, "Weather data", "Month", "Temperature", 0.5, 12.5, 0, 40,
            Color.LTGRAY, Color.LTGRAY);

    renderer.setXLabels(12);
    renderer.setYLabels(10);
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);

    XYValueSeries sunSeries = new XYValueSeries("Demo 1");
    sunSeries.add(1f, 35, 4.3);
    sunSeries.add(2f, 35, 4.9);
    sunSeries.add(3f, 35, 5.9);
    sunSeries.add(4f, 35, 8.8);
    sunSeries.add(5f, 35, 10.8);
    sunSeries.add(6f, 35, 11.9);
    sunSeries.add(7f, 35, 13.6);
    sunSeries.add(8f, 35, 12.8);
    sunSeries.add(9f, 35, 11.4);
    sunSeries.add(10f, 35, 9.5);
    sunSeries.add(11f, 35, 7.5);
    sunSeries.add(12f, 35, 5.5);
    XYSeriesRenderer lightRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    lightRenderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

    XYSeries waterSeries = new XYSeries("Demo 2");
    waterSeries.add(1, 16);
    waterSeries.add(2, 15);
    waterSeries.add(3, 16);
    waterSeries.add(4, 17);
    waterSeries.add(5, 20);
    waterSeries.add(6, 23);
    waterSeries.add(7, 25);
    waterSeries.add(8, 25.5);
    waterSeries.add(9, 26.5);
    waterSeries.add(10, 24);
    waterSeries.add(11, 22);
    waterSeries.add(12, 18);

    XYSeries waterSeries2 = new XYSeries("Demo 3");
    waterSeries2.add(1, 15);
    waterSeries2.add(2, 14);
    waterSeries2.add(3, 14);
    waterSeries2.add(4, 15);
    waterSeries2.add(5, 18);
    waterSeries2.add(6, 22);
    waterSeries2.add(7, 24);
    waterSeries2.add(8, 25);
    waterSeries2.add(9, 24);
    waterSeries2.add(10, 21);
    waterSeries2.add(11, 18);
    waterSeries2.add(12, 16);
    renderer.setBarSpacing(0.3);

    XYSeriesRenderer sunSeries1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    sunSeries1.setColor(0xff0011cc);
    sunSeries1.setChartValuesTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

    XYSeriesRenderer waterRenderer1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    waterRenderer1.setColor(0xff0099cc);
    waterRenderer1.setChartValuesTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

    XYSeriesRenderer waterRenderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    waterRenderer2.setColor(0xff9933cc);
    waterRenderer2.setChartValuesTextAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = buildDataset(titles, x, values);
    dataset.addSeries(0, sunSeries);
    dataset.addSeries(0, waterSeries);
    dataset.addSeries(0, waterSeries2);

    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(0, lightRenderer);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(0, waterRenderer1);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(0, waterRenderer2);
    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(50, 250, 210, 190));

    waterRenderer1.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    waterRenderer1.setChartValuesTextSize(10);

    waterRenderer2.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    waterRenderer2.setChartValuesTextSize(10);

    ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, dataset, renderer).setZoomRate(5f);

    ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, dataset, renderer).getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
    return ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, dataset, renderer).getPeer();

}
```

This method returns chart as component. I called this method in the form of:

```
chart =  demo.getCombinedTemperatureChart(context);
addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, chart);
```

With the older library the chart renders correctly but with the new library of CN1aChartEngine, I got this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.draw(XYChart.java:374)
    at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onDraw(GraphicalView.java:195)
    at org.achartengine.compat.View$Peer.run(View.java:208)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display$1.run(Display.java:775)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
[Task Thread] 0:0:0,0 - java.lang.NullPointerException
[Task Thread] 0:0:0,1 - java.lang.NullPointerException
```

While debugging I get that, this exception occurs when `form.show()` called not at the moment when the `getCombinedTemperatureChart(Context context)` method returns the chart component.
I didn't get why this exception occurs with the updated CN1aChartEngine library. Little help would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using the older 1.0.x line (i.e. using Pisces).  I have reproduced the problem (in that line) and fixed it.  You can download the latest at
https://github.com/shannah/CN1aChartEngine/releases/tag/1.0.2

Comment: Great work sir. But I got another issue with the library. Android build is failing with the new CN1achartEngine library. Here is [error.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8677v18iqbzhplz/error.txt?dl=0) I get from build-server. I get below exception in error.txt file.`[dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/codename1/charts/ChartComponent;`.  With the older version of library build was successful.

Comment: It is complaining that you have two instances of ChartComponent in your app.  One would be from Codename One.  Have you copied it into your app somewhere additionally?

Comment: No, its just happening with new library. Try with [CN1aChartEngineDemo](https://github.com/shannah/CN1aChartEngineDemo). Same issue here

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue.  Works fine for me.  The error message indicates that you have two copies of ChartComponent defined.  You need to track down where the 2nd one is coming from.